# How safe is to use Postgres multiple schemas?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, database-administration

Heroku warns of using Multiple Schemas with Postgres. But does not specify `numerous operational problems` caused.

As posted on Heroku docs:

> The most common use case for using multiple schemas in a database is
>   building a software-as-a-service application wherein each customer has
>   their own schema. While this technique seems compelling, we strongly
>   recommend against it as it has caused numerous cases of operational
>   problems. For instance, even a moderate number of schemas (> 50) can
>   severely impact the performance of Heroku’s database snapshots tool,
>   PG Backups.

I think, the problem of Backups can be solved by adding a follower db.

I have `60` tables per schema, so with `1000` schemas I will have `60,000` tables. How will this impact database performance? What kind of problems I can expect while scaling?

Comment: A very resourceful article written on the topic -> https://influitive.io/our-multi-tenancy-journey-with-postgres-schemas-and-apartment-6ecda151a21f

Comment: Off topic - why do you plan to create 1000 schemas with 60 tables each? It seems like a perfect case for table partitioning rather than making 1000 schemas?
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: `Schemas` provide solid data isolation, instead of managing `1000` databases managing `1000` schemas would be easier.

Comment: Managing 1 database with composite pk on a partitioned table will be much easier than 1000 schemas.

Answer (score 3):

The first issues with running a large volume of schemas and/or tables don't typically interfere with a running database. The major problem that operators encounter is that they will be unable to create logical backups of the database. Running `heroku pg:backups` is likely to fail as is running `pg_dump` manually. Typically, this is the error you'll see in the attempted backup logs:

```
ERROR: out of shared memory HINT: You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction
```

The large volume of locks needed end up causing OOM conditions for the database. This isn't always a problem on Heroku. If you're using a production database you can rely on their [point-in-time](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-rollback) recovery option as your DR solution. That being said, exporting the data off Heroku will be difficult if you can't run a logical backup since they don't currently support external replication. It's less than ideal but hypothetically you could try to dump the database schema by schema in order avoid the OOM conditions.

Comment: Will having thousands to table spread across schemas can be an issue at some point?
For eg. I have 60 tables per schema, so with 1000 schemas I will have 60,000 tables.

Comment: Yes, large volumes of tables can have a similar effect. I would fully expect to see the aforementioned issues with 60k tables across 1k schemas.

Comment: Except for logical backups for an application running in production can you foresee any other issue?